Cloud Function with Pub/Sub Trigger Fails to Save Email Attachments to Cloud Storage
I am building a Google Cloud Function with a Pub/Sub trigger to handle email attachments. The function is supposed to save the attachments from allowed email addresses into a specified Cloud Storage bucket.
While the Pub/Sub trigger works and logs confirm the function invocation, no attachments are being saved to the bucket. Additionally, in some cases, the function logs show "No valid attachments found in the email", even when valid attachments were included in the test emails.
Details of the Setup
Cloud Function:
Trigger: Pub/Sub Topic
Runtime: Python 3.9
Permissions: All relevant roles (Cloud Functions Invoker, Pub/Sub Publisher, Storage Admin) have been granted to the associated service accounts.
Pub/Sub Topic:
Topic created with default settings (add a subscription, pull delivery type, 7 days message retention).
Expected Flow:
Email attachments are received via Pub/Sub messages.
Function processes the Pub/Sub message, validates the sender and subject, and saves the attachments to a specified Cloud Storage bucket.
Current Observations:
Pub/Sub messages are successfully published, and the function logs show invocation.
However, no attachments are saved to the bucket.
In some cases, logs indicate "No valid attachments found in the email", despite valid attachments being sent.
Occasionally, emails are returned as undelivered, with no further error details in logs.
Code Snippet for Reference
Here is the code for the function. Any feedback or suggestions to identify the issue would be appreciated:
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def handle_email_attachment(cloud_event):
    """Handles email attachments sent via Pub/Sub."""
    try:
        pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(cloud_event.data["message"]["data"]).decode("utf-8")
        email_message = message_from_bytes(base64.b64decode(pubsub_message))

        # Extract sender, recipient, and subject
        sender_email = email_message.get("from", "").strip()
        recipient_email = email_message.get("to", "").strip()
        subject = email_message.get("subject", "").strip()

        # Validate sender email
        if sender_email not in ALLOWED_EMAILS:
            print(f"Email from {sender_email} is not allowed. Ignoring.")
            return

        # Process attachments
        for part in email_message.walk():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                continue
            if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                continue

            file_name = part.get_filename()
            file_data = part.get_payload(decode=True)
            if file_name:
                save_to_storage(sender_email, file_name, file_data)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing email attachment: {e}")

def save_to_storage(sender_email, file_name, file_data):
    """Save the attachment to Cloud Storage."""
    folder_name = sender_email.replace("@", "at").replace(".", "_")
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(ATTACHMENT_BUCKET)
    blob = bucket.blob(f"{folder_name}/{file_name}")
    blob.upload_from_string(file_data)
    print(f"File {file_name} uploaded to folder {folder_name} in bucket {ATTACHMENT_BUCKET}.")

Pub/Sub Message Structure:
Is there a specific Pub/Sub message structure required for email attachments to be processed correctly?
Validation of Email:
Does the "from" or "to" field format differ in Pub/Sub messages triggered by email providers like Gmail or other domains?
Attachment Handling:
Are there specific content types (e.g., text/csv, application/vnd.ms-excel) that must be explicitly handled in the Cloud Function?
Testing Environment:
Are there additional steps required to debug Pub/Sub-triggered Cloud Functions, specifically for attachment handling?

How is the data for the Pub/Sub messages being encoded before being published? It appears that you are decoding from base64 twice, which indicates that the emails are being base64-encoded in the publisher client before being published, as they are also base64-encoded by Pub/Sub before being sent to Cloud Run. It's possible that there is data corruption caused by improper encoding or decoding that prevents the bytes representing the email from being parsed properly. Additional logging within the email_message.walk() loop can help to check that the parts of the email are being parsed correctly.

From what I understand, you are trying to save email attachments into a specific Google Cloud Storage but there are no attachments being saved to the bucket.
The first thing you need to consider here is the necessary permissions or roles to the associated service account to create objects in the Cloud Storage bucket or verify that the function has the correct permissions on the Cloud Storage bucket. Double-check roles like Storage Object Admin or at least Storage Object Creator.
To answer your questions:
Is there a specific Pub/Sub message structure required for email attachments to be processed correctly?

Yes, Pub/Sub messages sent by the email service (e.g., Gmail) must contain the Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) email content. Based on the structure you're expecting in cloud_event.data should be correct.

Does the "from" or "to" field format differ in Pub/Sub messages triggered by email providers like Gmail or other domains?

Yes, Gmail usually has From, To, and Subject to its headers as expected while for the others, they have unique headers and ways of encoding especially if they’re using custom formats or headers.

Are there specific content types (e.g., text/csv, application/vnd.ms-excel) that must be explicitly handled in the Cloud Function?

Yes, your current code does not check for specific content types for attachments (e.g., application/pdf, image/jpeg). If you want to filter attachments by type (only save PDFs or images), you can modify the code to check part.get_content_type() before saving the file.
if part.get_content_type() == 'application/pdf':
    # Only save PDF attachments
    file_name = part.get_filename()
    file_data = part.get_payload(decode=True)
    save_to_storage(sender_email, file_name, file_data)



Are there additional steps required to debug Pub/Sub-triggered Cloud Functions, specifically for attachment handling?

Utilize the use of logging in the Cloud Run Function, use print() statements to log the parsed email fields, attachment details (like filenames), and any errors encountered. Ensure that your logging is thorough at every step of processing the email.

For example:
print(f"Attachment found: {file_name}, Content-Type: {part.get_content_type()}")

